# NullReferenceException after creating new parent class property

Tags: c#

I would imagine this is quite a basic question in C#.  I've got my head in a bit of spin with it though and I'm unsure of the correct way of sorting it.

I have a parent class with get/set properties and with a child class.  When an instance of the class is created using **new** the property to the parent class is accessible but the child class isn't.  I remember in C programming you have to create the memory space for this but I'm unsure of the correct way of doing this in C#.

**Parent Class**

```
class Parent_class
{
    private int number;
    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set { number = value; }
    }
    private Child_class childclass;// = new Child_class();
    public Child_class Childclass
    {
        get { return childclass; }
        set { childclass = value; }
    }
}
```

**Child Class**

```
class Child_class
{
    private int number;
    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set { number = value; }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parent_class test = new Parent_class();
        test.Number = 3;            //<--Ok
        test.Childclass.Number = 4; //<--NullReferenceException
    }
```

Comment: You have created an instance of "Parent_class" to use that class. So where is your "Child_class" instance to use that class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the field-backed getter / setter if you aren't doing anything special -- the compiler can create that for you.

To obtain an instance of a class, you need to use `new`. Since it looks like you want `Parent_class` to have an instance of child class automatically, you can do that in the `constructor`.

Oh - and the reason why Number works fine is that's a `primitive` type, and not a class. Primitives,  (int, float, bool, double, DateTime, TimeSpan, to name a few) do not need instantiation via `new`.

**Parent Class**

```
public class Parent_class
{
    public Parent_class()
    {
      Childclass = new Child_class();
    }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public Child_class Childclass { get; set; }
}
```

**Child Class**

```
public class Child_class
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

**Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Parent_class test = new Parent_class();
    test.Number = 3;            //<--Ok
    test.Childclass.Number = 4;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It gives a little bit more information that has helped me understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created Instance of Child class.

You can do either of below

1. Initialize just before use

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Parent_class test = new Parent_class();
       test.Number = 3;            //<--Ok
       test.ChildClass = new Child_class(); 
       test.Childclass.Number = 4; //<--NullReferenceException
   }
   ```

   2 . Initialize in the parent ctor

   ```
       public Parent_class()
       {
       Childclass = new Child_class();
       }
   ```

3 . Initialize inline at the time of declaration

```
   private Child_class childclass = new Child_class();
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, especially with the extra ways of doing it. Is there one preferred way of doing it?